# Sorting on Page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am Working on VF page in which i have used Angular js. What I am doing is bring data from custom object using query inside controller anf then serializing its using json.serialisation.using that string on VFPage . Now I am displaying that on page. I have copied code from a blog what it does is display record with pagination and does the sorting of the record on particular. What I want is it should do sorting for the whole data. below is the code..
lodata is the serialized data that I am bringing from controller

```
  var myapp = angular.module('hello', []);
  var sortingOrder = '';
  var sortingOrderWO = 'createdDateWO';
  //var $scope;
  var new_sorting_order = null;


         //this.$scope = $scope;
         //this.$filter =$filter;
         $scope.sortingOrder = sortingOrder;
         $scope.reverse = false;
         $scope.filteredItems = [];
         $scope.groupedItems = [];
         $scope.itemsPerPage = 15;
         $scope.pagedItems = [];
         $scope.currentPage = 0;                 
         $scope.items = lodata;

          var searchMatch = function (haystack, needle) {
             if (!needle) {
                 return true;
             }
             return haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
          };

          //Initialize the Search Filters 
          $scope.search = function () {
             $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items, function (item) {
                 for (var attr in item) {
                     if (searchMatch(item[attr], $scope.query))
                         return true;
                 }
                 return false;
             });
             // Define Sorting Order
             if ($scope.sortingOrder !== '') {
                 $scope.filteredItems = $filter('orderBy')($scope.filteredItems, $scope.sortingOrder, !$scope.reverse);
             }
             $scope.currentPage = 0;
             // console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.filteredItems));
             // Group by pages
             $scope.groupToPages();
          };

          $scope.groupToPages = function () {
             $scope.pagedItems = [];
             for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filteredItems.length; i++) {
                 if (i % $scope.itemsPerPage === 0) {
                     $scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / $scope.itemsPerPage)] = [$scope.filteredItems[i]];
                 } else {
                     $scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / $scope.itemsPerPage)].push($scope.filteredItems[i]);
                 }
             }
          };

          $scope.range = function (start, end) {
                     var ret = [];
                     if (!end) {
                         end = start;
                         start = 0;
                     }
                     for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
                         ret.push(i);
                     }
                     return ret;
                 };

          $scope.prevPage = function () {
                     if ($scope.currentPage > 0) {
                         $scope.currentPage--;
                     }
                 };
          $scope.nextPage = function () {
                     if ($scope.currentPage < $scope.pagedItems.length - 1) {
                         $scope.currentPage++;
                     }
                 };

          $scope.setPage = function () {
                     $scope.currentPage = this.n;
                 };                            

          $scope.search();

          $scope.sort_by = function (newSortingOrder) {
                     //alert(sortingOrder + '-----' +newSortingOrder);
                     //alert($scope.sortingOrder); 
                     //alert('Sort called in one direction'); 
                     if ($scope.sortingOrder == newSortingOrder){                            
                         $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;   
                         //alert('we are changing the reverse'+$scope.reverse);                          
                     }                          
                     $scope.sortingOrder = newSortingOrder;
                     //alert('we are changing the $scope.sortingOrder'+$scope.sortingOrder);
                     // icon setup
                     $('th i').each(function () {
                         // icon reset
                         $(this).removeClass().addClass('icon-sort');
                     });
                     if ($scope.reverse)
                         $('th.' + new_sorting_order + ' i').removeClass().addClass('icon-chevron-up');
                     else
                         $('th.' + new_sorting_order + ' i').removeClass().addClass('icon-chevron-down');
                 };
     }

     var contrl = controllers.controller('ctrlRead', function ($scope, $filter){
         //alert('its started');
         var locData =  {!wpData[0]}
         return generateJson(locData, $scope, $filter);
         //alert('its completed');
     });   
     contrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$filter'];
```

Comment: It does sorting for data on particular Page.  I want the sorting should work for whole data(last record on last page should come as first record on first page and vice-versa)

Comment: does 'lodata' contain the whole array?

Comment: yes lodata contains the whole array.. I mean all the records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [angularjs table](http://angularjsaz.blogspot.com/2015/09/angularjs-table-sorting-filter-and.html) via filter, sort on page and paging example.

Example code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
 <head>  
   <title>Angular JS table sort and filter example </title>  
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
   <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>  
   <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular-resource.js"></script>  
   <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>  
   <script>  
     var app = angular.module('MyForm', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngResource']);  
     app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {  
       $scope.predicate = 'name';  
       $scope.reverse = true;  
       $scope.currentPage = 1;  
       $scope.order = function (predicate) {  
         $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;  
         $scope.predicate = predicate;  
       };  
       $scope.students = [  
         { name: 'Kevin', age: 25, gender: 'boy' },  
         { name: 'John', age: 30, gender: 'girl' },  
         { name: 'Laura', age: 28, gender: 'girl' },  
         { name: 'Joy', age: 15, gender: 'girl' },  
         { name: 'Mary', age: 28, gender: 'girl' },  
         { name: 'Peter', age: 95, gender: 'boy' },  
         { name: 'Bob', age: 50, gender: 'boy' },  
         { name: 'Erika', age: 27, gender: 'girl' },  
         { name: 'Patrick', age: 40, gender: 'boy' },  
         { name: 'Tery', age: 60, gender: 'girl' }  
       ];  
       $scope.totalItems = $scope.students.length;  
       $scope.numPerPage = 5;  
       $scope.paginate = function (value) {  
         var begin, end, index;  
         begin = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage;  
         end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;  
         index = $scope.students.indexOf(value);  
         return (begin <= index && index < end);  
       };  
     });  
   </script>  
   <style>  
     .odd {  
       background-color: antiquewhite;  
       color: #008b8b;  
     }  
     td th {  
       height: 30px;  
       min-width: 100px;  
     }  
     thead {  
       background-color: darkgray;  
       color: white;  
       height: 30px;  
     }  
   </style>  
 </head>  
 <body ng-app="MyForm">  
   <div ng-controller="myCtrl">  
     <h3>List students</h3>  
     <div class="container-fluid">  
       <pre>Click header link to sort, input into filter text to filter</pre>  
       <hr />  
       <table class="table table-striped">  
         <thead>  
           <tr>  
             <th>Edit</th>  
             <th>  
               <a href="" ng-click="order('name')">Name</a>  
             </th>  
             <th><a href="" ng-click="order('age')"> Age</a> </th>  
             <th><a href="" ng-click="order('gender')">Gender</a> </th>  
           </tr>  
         </thead>  
         <tbody>  
           <tr>  
             <td>Filter =>></td>  
             <td> <input type="text" ng-model="search.name" /></td>  
             <td> <input type="text" ng-model="search.age" /> </td>  
             <td><input type="text" ng-model="search.gender" /> </td>  
           </tr>  
           <tr ng-repeat="user in students | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:paginate| filter:search" ng-class-odd="'odd'">  
             <td>  
               <button class="btn">  
                 Edit  
               </button>  
             </td>  
             <td>{{ user.name}}</td>  
             <td>{{ user.age}}</td>  
             <td>{{ user.gender}}</td>  
           </tr>  
         </tbody>  
       </table>  
       <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage"  
             max-size="5" boundary-links="true"  
             items-per-page="numPerPage" class="pagination-sm">  
       </pagination>  
     </div>  
   </div>  
 </body>  
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are doing the filter first. What I would do is do the sort first then do the filter. This may be a slight performance hit but it will definitely give you what you need.

Change this:

```
$scope.search = function () {
    $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items, function (item) {
        for (var attr in item) {
            if (searchMatch(item[attr], $scope.query))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
    // Define Sorting Order
    if ($scope.sortingOrder !== '') {
        $scope.filteredItems = $filter('orderBy')($scope.filteredItems, $scope.sortingOrder, !$scope.reverse);
    }
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    // console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.filteredItems));
    // Group by pages
    $scope.groupToPages();
};
```

To this:

```
 $scope.search = function () {
    // Define Sorting Order
    if ($scope.sortingOrder !== '') {
        $scope.items = $filter('orderBy')($scope.items, $scope.sortingOrder, !$scope.reverse);
    }

    $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items, function (item) {
        for (var attr in item) {
            if (searchMatch(item[attr], $scope.query))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    // console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.filteredItems));
    // Group by pages
    $scope.groupToPages();
};
```

This is untested. As you can see i just swapped pieces of code. This will sort the array first and then filter it. Let me know if you have problems.

Comment: It did not worked out. what it did is sort data on each page(last record on page 1 to be the first record on page 1 and so on) rather then sorting the whole data(i mean it should bring the last record on last page as first record on first page)

Comment: Are you saying that you want the order to be reversed?

Comment: I guess you are using this example, from ur comment - http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/webtech/web/pagination-and-sorting-of-data-table-using-angularjs/#comment-1719142640 , then on on line 103, you need to pass complete array instead of $scope.filteredList.

Comment: Yes , I wanted things to get reverse.